# Кросс-доменные запросы из injected script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Ситуация такова: расширение внедряет некоторый скрипт в страницу, который должен выполнить кросс-доменный запрос. Соответственно, страница блокирует запрос, печатая следующую ошибку:

> Refused to connect to 'https://example.com/script.js' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src
> 'self' blob: blob ...

Так же я заметил, что над `XMLHttpRequest` существует некоторая обёртка (поскольку ошибка происходит не на вызове метода `open`, а на вызове другого метода, который следует за ним). Как можно решить данную проблему? Ошибка довольно таки "стандартная" для таких ситуаций, и мне кажется обёртка тут роли не играет, я прав?

Comment: Есть такой механизм защиты CORS. Суть в том что сервер должен явно указать с какого домена (или маску) разрешается выполнить запрос

Comment: Да, я видел в ответах сервера прописанный список доменов, на которые разрешается выполнение запросов. Как это можно обойти?

Comment: Кажется я догадался. Нужно лишь подписаться на `webRequest.onHeadersReceived` и менять значение заголовка `content-security-policy` добавляя после строчки `"connect-src 'self' blob: blob ` нужный домен.

Answer (score 0):

Это решается просто. В первую очередь, у расширения должны быть права на домен - или на конкретный или `"<all_urls>"`. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/declare_permissions/).

Далее. Если вы будете подключать скрипт через `.appendChild(scriptElement)`, загруженный скрипт будет исполнятся в контексте страницы, на него будут действовать ограничения контекста страницы и не будут действовать полномочия расширения.

Вам нужно подключить скрит [через манифест](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#declaratively) или [програмно из background.js](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#programmatic). В таком случае расширение сможет слать запросы куда захотите, будет иметь доступ к DOM страницы, **НО** у него не будет доступа к переменным области видимости обычных переменных сайта.

Такое ограничение обходится просто: подключается один скрипт первым способом, один - вторым, и они общаются с помощю [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

---

Comment: В комментариях я изложил более удобнее решение.